# top-down menu not displaying

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, web-applications, pug

I am using bootstrap for this implementation. So I followed the guidlines in creating a top-down menu from [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns/) . This top-down menu should contain a room List. The menu is called 'Rooms'. My Jade and Javascript files are below(just the implementation of the top-down menu)

editor.jade

```
extends layout

block header
script(src='/javascripts/editor.js')

block content
h1(id="title") Editor

h2 Editor: #{editorName}
.dropdown
 button#dropdownMenu1.btn.dropdown-toggle.sr-only(type='button', data-toggle='dropdown')
  | Rooms
  span.caret
 ul.dropdown-menu(role='menu', aria-labelledby='dropdownMenu1')
  #rooms
...
```

editor.js(javascript)

```
...
$.getJSON("/getContents", {theRoom: "roomList"},  function(room) {

   room.activeRooms.forEach(function(theExit){

       $('#rooms').replaceWith('<li  id="rooms" role="presentation">' + theExit+'</li>')
   });
});
...
```

Unfortunately, there is no top-down menu displayed on the screen. Can you please look at my code and tell me what I did wrong?

PS If my question is not clear, can you please tell me so that I can elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the http request is filled and the callback is called. Then, replace your jquery part with something like this:

```
rooms.forEach(function(room){
    $('.dropdown-menu').append('<li role="presentation">' +room+' trolol</li>')
});
```

What you do now is replace the `#rooms` elements with the first iteration of `forEach`, then it doesn't exist anymore and jquery can't find it.

http://jsfiddle.net/t6N9R/3/

(I converted the jade to HTML using one of the online converters)

Comment: The id, #rooms will no longer be useful in the jade file, right?

Comment: It was never useful :)